# Run a perfmon System Performance data collector set remotely?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, performance-monitoring

I was wondering how can I run the System Performance built-in data collector set on a remote computer.

I have a Windows Server 2008 management box and a Windows Server 2003 target box which I need to obtain performance data on. I have created a custom data collector set to gather various performance data such as CPU usage, Memory usage, etc, however I have found that the built-in System Performance data collector set is much more detailed and exactly what I needed (comes with those nice xml/html detailed reports and with a NT Kernel trace).

I was wondering if I can configure an user defined data collector set using the System Performance set as a template, but run it remotely on my Windows 2003 server.

Any ideas? I was thinking of building the counters from scratch and instead of the Local Computer select the remote target, but there must be a cleaner way to do it just by using the template?

Note that the server is completely cut-off from the internet, downloading any performance analysis tool is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking about this and I came up with the following solution, not sure if it's the cleanest, but it works.

Basically, I recreated the Data Collector Set from scratch and instead of using Manual setup I used a template (System Performance). Afterwards, I deleted the default counters and recreated them using the remote computer counters instead.